# How to write this? Substitution after differentiation. Image in description

Tags: math-mode

I want to create the formula which is in the picture. It is basically substitution after differentiation, how to express this in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_y`

[image]

Explanation: `\left.` and `\right|` add a pair of delimiters that grow with the fraction, and of which the left delimiter is invisible and the right one is the vertical bar.

If you want to control the size of the bar, you could do `\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_y` and choose, instead of `\Big`, sizes such as `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`.